# wordpress acf date trouble

Tags: php, wordpress, date

**Hello!**

I set an ACF called *`pst_date`* and filled it with `'03.05.2015'` on a post.
In my template I'm using:

`<?php echo get_field('pst_date'); ?>`

Output shows `02.05.2015`.

Same happens for other years even 2020.
Now I was curious and tried other dates and both input `'29.03.2015'` and `'30.03.2015'` have same output of `'29.03.2015'`.

**Before** the date `'29.03.2015'` it shows the correct date.
After `'29.03.2015'` it is one day short.

Same happens for other dates passed the last sunday of march.
So I assume its some DST bug.

Is there any workaround / fix?
Google was not helpful with that particular problem.

> wordpress 5.3.2
>   php 7.0 / 7.1 / 7.2 / 7.3

Thank you.

Comment: Hi. What type of field is `pst_date`?

Comment: If you are using the date field of the ACF plugin you have an option for output format, try tinkering with them, if that doesn't work it could be a a time difference, check [date_default_timezone_set](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Comment: hello and thank you. 'pst_date' is of type **DATE** using the jquery date picker of ACF to set the value '03.05.2015'. I do know the format ist stored as 'Ymd' in the field. but I'm not woried about the FORMAT. I have trouble with the shown VALUE.

I'm setting jsut the DATE as it is called date picker. I do have no say about the timestamp of the field. I can't be the only one who is using this and have trouble with DST.
My template stays in same time zone, nothing is changed from admin to frontend? and why the heck has a DATE field a DST problem?

Comment: please be advised. I checked the input in the database.
Input of '03.05.2015' in field 'pst_date' of type DATE leads to a value of '20150503' in the corresponding database entry. In my novice brain I tought when using get_field('pst_date') it would lead to the output of '03.05.2015'. Somewhere in the get_field output conversion of a string-format there must be some unwanted date conversion.

Comment: and aditionally ... as I know the date is stored as 'Ymd' in the database. So I changed the ACF output format to 'Ymd' which should mean no conversion.
But date '03.05.2015' stored as '20150503' in DB get an get_field('pst_date') of '20150502' am I stubid or is there a major UUPSIE in the ACF/wordpress date get_field?